# Image sequence animation to mimic Marvel intro

Tags: jquery, image, animation, sequence, velocity

I'd like to create an animation to mimic the [Marvel comic intro](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w8gBSy0W9LE), but using my own images. I'm not sure if it is better to create the animation as a video and embed that in my web page or if I can use jQuery/Velocity to achieve this effect?

I apologise in advance if this question is too vague or not of use to many people, but I am struggling to find a solution through Google searches.

Thanks in advance for any help/direction on this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who is interested, this is how I achieved close to what I wanted, based on this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ddrace/DJuV7/1/

```
#intro {
position: relative;
margin:auto;
top: 50px;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
height: 600px;
width:800px;
background: #fff;
}

#intro div {
    position: absolute;
    top: -360px;
}

<script>
    $(function () {
        $('.image-sequence').hide();

        var pause = 200;
        var motion = 300;

        var quotes = $('.image-sequence');
        var count = quotes.length;
        var i = 0;

        setTimeout(transition, pause);

        function transition() {                
            quotes.eq(i).animate({ opacity: 'toggle', top: '0' }, motion);

            i++;

            if (i == count) return;

            setTimeout(transition, pause);
        }
    });
</script>

<div id="intro">
<div class="image-sequence">
    <img src="~/Images/relational-sequence-1.jpg">
</div>
<div class="image-sequence">
    <img src="~/Images/relational-sequence-2.jpg">
</div>
<div class="image-sequence">
    <img src="~/Images/relational-sequence-3.jpg">
</div>
<div class="image-sequence">
    <img src="~/Images/relational-sequence-4.jpg">
</div>
<div class="image-sequence">
    <img src="~/Images/relational-sequence-5.jpg">
</div>
<div class="image-sequence">
    <img src="~/Images/relational-sequence-6.jpg">
</div>
<div class="image-sequence">
    <img src="~/Images/relational-sequence-7.jpg">
</div>
<div class="image-sequence">
    <img src="~/Images/relational-sequence-8.jpg">
</div>
<div class="image-sequence">
    <img src="~/Images/relational-sequence-9.jpg">
</div>
<div class="image-sequence">
    <img src="~/Images/relational-sequence-10.jpg">
</div>
<div class="image-sequence">
    <img src="~/Images/relational-sequence-11.jpg">
</div>
<div class="image-sequence">
    <img src="~/Images/relational-sequence-12.jpg">
</div>
<div class="image-sequence">
    <img src="~/Images/relational-sequence-13.jpg">
</div>
<div class="image-sequence">
    <img src="~/Images/relational-sequence-14.jpg">
</div>
<div class="image-sequence">
    <img src="~/Images/relational-sequence-15.jpg">
</div>
<div class="image-sequence">
    <img src="~/Images/relational-sequence-16.jpg">
</div>
```